# User defined fields (spreadsheet-like database design, tabular data) with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

Basically what i'm trying to design is spreadsheets of data with MongoDB, or lets call it tabular data, where user can define arbitrary number of columns/rows for spreadsheet that needs to be persisted.

The thing is that name of the columns itself, their data types that they will hold and metadata like is column unique, default value for it, order in which should appear, etc... **is not known in advance.**

Based on similar questions i went through, there could be few approaches

1. EAV (entity-attribute-value with SQL which i would like to avoid by any means)
2. SQL solution with JSON/JSONB columns to keep data (which i would like to avoid cause a lot of cells update can be expected)
3. NoSQL with MongoDB, which seems to me as most natural fit for problem like this.

Lets imagine for the sake of simplicity, we have user defined table 2 x 2, that looks something like following. Table name is "Parking spots" and table description is "List of our parking spots".

| Parking type | Number od spots |
| --- | --- |
| garage | 10 |
| public | 100 |

Requirement is that, there will be more than one organization of users who can create tables (lets call them tenants).

My best way to go with MongoDB for this would to create **single** MongoDB collections lets call it `tables` that would hold documents as described below, holding `tenantId` field as well. So basically one single document in collection "tables" would hold one single table defined by specific tenant.

```
[
  {
    "_id":"507f1f77bcf86cd799439011",
    "name":"Parking spots",
    "description":"List of our parking spots",
    "tenantId":1,
    "createdAt":"2023-03-08T15:47:49.382Z",
    "updatedAt":"2023-03-08T15:47:49.382Z",
    "columns":[
      {
        "name":"parkingType",
        "displayName":"Parking type",
        "order":1,
        "unique":false,
        "defaultValue":"public",
        "dataType":"string",
        "cells":[
          {
            "rowIndex":1,
            "value":"garage"
          },
          {
            "rowIndex":2,
            "value":"public"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name":"numberOfSpots",
        "displayName":"Number of spots",
        "order":2,
        "unique":false,
        "defaultValue":100,
        "dataType":"number",
        "cells":[
          {
            "rowIndex":1,
            "value":10
          },
          {
            "rowIndex":2,
            "value":100
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Having not so great expirience with MongoDB i would be really thankful for any kind of advices when it comes to:

- how resilient this solution is when it comes to many operation that user can do with spreadsheet, like re-ordering columns, re-ordering rows most importantly sorting all rows based on one single column, like sorting above per "Number of slots"?
- how this design would go along with MongoDB aggregation framework and standard operations that can be performed on table?
- how one would create unique index in a way to ensure that whatever column is unique, and that no more than one value can appear in all column cells?
- any potential bottlenecks? having in mind that user can defined arbitrary number of columns/rows and do standard operation on them (like doing MIN, AVG, etc operations)
- i know limit of one single document size in MongoDB is 16MB, im not expecting large tables
- any other design for this that could be considered?

Answer (score 0):

1. MongoDB isn't ACID compliant by the normal definition. So at best you should only allow a single user to modify a table at a time (given the current design). Google Sheets use Operational Transforms to implement their live
   collaboration. Specifically they use Server-based Operational
   Transforms. If you forgo any form of collaboration algorithms, then
   you have at best a table that can be modified by one person and
   viewed by many others. If you don't then you run into diverging
   local and remote state. But if your users are operating on different
   tables, it should be fine.
2. It's just a collection of documents like any other MongoDB collection. All the standard operations *could* be performed on the collection. Whether they are useful or not is entirely up to your implementation.
3. Look at [MongoDB Unique Indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-on-a-single-field) for how to create it. If you are looking for how to make a unique constraint for each column then you would have to have columns be their own collection and possibly use a compound index instead of a single field index.
4. There isn't enough context to truly give a good answer here. I would make sure that the database is **not** doing the calculations because that might cause issues for other users. Also you are never modifying a single field, you would be replacing documents because otherwise MongoDB's lack of ACID compliance can bite you.
5. Look at how Open Office handles their spreadsheet format [[1](http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php)]. This works in a regular database and probably even a document store like MongoDB.

---

More information on point 2.

You could just treat the position of a cell (given by a tuple of `(row, column)`) as a key and the value of the cell would be the value within an object. Then only save cells with a value in the database.

You could also amortize the search time by making it a slightly more complex:

```json
{"cells": {
    "<cell row position>": {
       "<cell column position>":"<cell value>"
    }
}}
```

You would need to take into account access patterns, where the data is being manipulated, and how updates are being applied.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer

Regarding above points, and especially point 2.
that is what im trying to solve, to find some design that is good to start with. My proposed solution, as i found out, is not that good. "cells" array is unbounded array with potentially will grow to thousands and thousands

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer for more elaboration on the design space. Check out [this](https://iq.opengenus.org/data-structure-for-spreadsheet/#openofficesimplementation) regarding the data structures used to represent spreadsheets as well which provide some details on how they work and how they perform. 

Again it all depends on the use case.